# How can I change the priority of a resource request in SimPy after yielding the request?

Tags: python, simpy

I'm modeling a manufacturing system where machines can fail randomly and request a technician for repair with a specified priority. However, while a machine is waiting for a technician to become available, its priority could change. Is this something I can model in SimPy? The relevant part of my code is below:

```
with technician.request(priority=self.get_priority()) as req:
    yield req
    yield self.env.timeout(self.time_to_repair)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an answer to this while trying to solve another problem that uses a request's `cancel()` method, as described in detail in Section 2 of [Advanced Features of the SimPy Language](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/156/PLN/AdvancedSimPy.pdf).

In my specific example, I have a `Machine` class that runs several processes. Within an instance of `Machine`, the request is first yielded within an environment process:

```
self.req = technician.request(priority=self.get_priority())
yield self.req
```

Another environment process can cancel the request later and generate a new one:

```
self.req.cancel()
self.req = technician.request(priority=self.get_priority())
yield self.req
```